# approx_fprime - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scipy, gradient, conv-neural-network

I am getting the error (title) when I execute `approx_fprime`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as op
def J(x):
    return x*x

xk = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3).astype('float32')
print(op.approx_fprime(xk.ravel(), J, 0.01))
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

I have to change the function, which ought to return a scalar instead of a vector.

```
def J(x): 
    return np.sum(x**2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invalidating the assumptions of [approx_fprime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.approx_fprime.html):

> Finite-difference approximation of the **gradient of a scalar function**.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ...
>
> f : callable
>
> The function of which to determine the gradient (partial derivatives). Should take xk as first argument, other arguments to f can be supplied in *args. **Should return a scalar, the value of the function at xk**.

You are returning, in this case, a vector of size 9. That's not what a scalar-function should return. The reason is simple:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
print((x*x).shape)
# (3,)
```

Comment: ok. if I change the function to `def J(x):
    return np.sum(x**2)`. I get the output: `[ 2.01  4.01  6.01  8.01 10.01 12.01 14.01 16.01 18.01]
`